# Passing JQuery variable to an external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, html

I use HTML5 Geolocation API to get latitude and longitude and then I want to pass that variables to an external PHP file. That PHP file(getPosition.php) returns me JSON variables from my database and then I get it on geo.js file to create markers on Google Maps.
On geo.js I also call getPosition.php to create markers on Google Maps

**geo.js (variables to get on the PHP file)**

```
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 $.getJSON('js/getPosition.php', function (data) {
```

**getPosition.php**

//This line returns me closest commerces arround me (1km) and I need my location to get commerces arround.

```
$lat = HERE I WANT LATITUDE FROM geo.js;
$lng = HERE I WANT LONGITUDE FROM geo.js;
$distance = 1;//Kms
$all = connectDB() -> query('SELECT commerce_name,commerce_offer,commerce_icon,commerce_lat,commerce_lng, (6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(commerce_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(' . $lat . ')) + COS(RADIANS(commerce_lng - ' . $lng . ')) * COS(RADIANS(commerce_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(' . $lat . ')))) AS distance FROM commerce WHERE (commerce_lat BETWEEN ' . $box['min_lat']. ' AND ' . $box['max_lat'] . ') AND (commerce_lng BETWEEN ' . $box['min_lng']. ' AND ' . $box['max_lng']. ') HAVING distance  < ' . $distance . ' ORDER BY distance ASC ');
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

I tried this on geo.js:

```
window.location.href = "zonazul.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng;
```

But its looping all the time, I also tried to get variables via AJAX but didnt work...
I'm lost

Comment: Hi, You need to post the variable to other page ?

Comment: Maybe `print_r($_GET)` and see what you have ? Also you are getting data as `json` maybe you should read about it : http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the data using ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {lat:latitude,log:longitude},
        url: "js/getPosition.php",
        success: function(data){
            }
        });
```

js/getPosition.php file:

```
 $lat = $_REQUEST['lat'];
 $lng = $_REQUEST['log'];
```

Comment: Perfect!!! I just need to add "dataType: 'json'," and it worked! Thank you so much I love you, I was working about it for 2 days... you are big!